# Vue single file component and SugarSS from PostCSS with Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, postcss, webpack-2

I'm trying to use SugarSS in Vue single file components and Webpack 2, but no luck so far. Here's my component file:

```
<template lang="pug">
  h1 hello!
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {message: "hello!"}
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="postcss">
  h1
    color: green
    display: flex
</style>
```

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./browser.js",
  output: {
    filename: "static/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["latest"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
        options: {
          postcss: {
            options: {
              parser: require("sugarss")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also have postcss.config.js just in case, in the same directory:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("sugarss")
  ]
}
```

I tried using `<style scoped lang="sugarss">` but no luck too. Here's the error code when running webpack:

```
TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found. Please check your PostCSS Config
    at /home/piotr/herd/js/node_modules/postcss-load-plugins/lib/plugins.js:46:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at plugins (/home/piotr/herd/js/node_modules/postcss-load-plugins/lib/plugins.js:23:15)
    at /home/piotr/herd/js/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:67:18
Hash: 2b260e6f43cbdf7bfbc1
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 1429ms
           Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
static/bundle.js  179 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 9 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-067de399&scoped=true!./~/postcss-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./userlist.vue
Module build failed: Missed semicolon (15:10)

  13 | 
  14 | h1
> 15 |   color: green
     |          ^
  16 |   display: flex
  17 | 

 @ ./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-067de399&scoped=true!./~/postcss-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./userlist.vue 4:14-256
```

To verify that everything is installed, I created a simple test.sss file with the same styles as in the component (color: green and display: flex) and run postcss from the cli, like this: `node_modules/.bin/postcss -p sugarss test.sss` - it works perfectly and outputs processed CSS as expected.

As far as vue-loader config, I'm using suggestions from the bottom of the page, here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/postcss.html

One more thing, when I switched the style tag to SASS, it worked well and webpack compiled the component without problems.

Am I missing something in the webpack config file?

Comment: Hm, did you have installed postcss-loader for webpack ? I think it doesn't come with the packed with vue-loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `postcss.config.js` is incorrect, sugarss is not a plugin, it is a parser. `postcss.config.js` should read:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: "sugarss"
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.